# How can I prove a formula for integration by parts for matrix functions?

Tags: matrices

Questions asks

State and prove a formula for integration by parts in which the integrands are matrices

functions.

But, For any given matrices, we can differentiate and integrate by considering every entry

of given matrix.

So, question itself seems quite obvious, just replace function with matrix functions?

How can I mathematically prove this?

Comment: Hint: integration by parts is about reverse-engineering the product rule. What product rule do you have for matrix-valued functions of a real variable?

Comment: isn't product rule for matrices functions basically same as product rule for real-valued function? as long as I keep the orders of matrices

Comment: Yep, I wrote it out a bit more in an answer, these comments only go so far.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{ n \times n}$ be matrix-valued differentiable functions of a real-variable. By definition, $\left( \frac{dA}{dt} \right)_{ij} = \frac{dA_{ij}}{dt}$ and thus,
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (AB)_{ij} = \frac{d}{dt} \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj} = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{dA_{ik}}{dt} B_{kj} + A_{ik}\frac{dB_{kj}}{dt} \right) = \left( \frac{dA}{dt}B+A\frac{dB}{dt}  \right)_{ij}. $$
The calculation above shows the product rule extends to matrix-products provided we are careful to maintain the order of the products. To integrate such a function we integrate component-wise. I suggest you consider the identity:
$$ U \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( UV  \right) - \frac{dU}{dt}V$$
Notice, the order of $U,V$ is important as matrix-multiplication does not commute.

Comment: Next, integrate the expression above, do we want a definite or indefinite integral? I'm not sure from your question thus far...